# windows batch command not running in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have created a small program to write some values in excel sheet using C#.
I am able to run the Prog.exe successfully and also using command promt.

I am trying to build a job i Jenkins which will just run this Prog.exe file. 
I can access the Jenkins in my browser. But when I try to build this job, it will not build. In the output console, I have to close the build because it will not build for an hour. I am giving directory address in Use custom workspace, and then Prog.exe in build tab, execute windows batch command.

[image: Jenkins Job Configuration]What can be the problem ? [image: jenkins job console output]

Comment: Post the jenkins job configuration and console output error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, C# program created using Windows Form Application cannot be run in Jenkins.

The reason is that, the forms application end up in continuous loop which prevents Jenkins from building the job.